# Is it possible to parse the CSV rows into JsonNodes having the correct value types

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

Its easy to parse a csv into a `List<Map<String,String>>` as described in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv#with-column-names-from-first-row

However, then, type inference has to be done manually. E.g. like the stuff I try to do below? Using `Boolean.parseBoolean` etc feels like bloat to me, as jackson does all that stuff pretty nicely...

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

ObjectReader with = mapper.readerFor(ArrayNode.class).with(schema);
mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY);
JsonNode readTree = with.readTree(new FileInputStream(file));

JsonNode jsonNode = arrayNode.get(0);
if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = jsonNode.fields();
    int counter = 0;
    while (fields.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fields.next();
        JsonNode value = entry.getValue();
        if (value.isBoolean()) {
            // nah
        } else if (value.isNumber()) {
            // yeah
        } else if (value.isTextual()) {
            // nah
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to parse the CSV rows into JsonNodes having the correct value types without relying on a POJO to provide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to read your question.

> Is it **theoretically** possible to parse the CSV rows into JsonNodes having the correct value types .... ?

The answer is Yes.  For example:

- You can write your own CSV parser from scratch that emits `JsonNode` objects.
- You can take the `List<Map<String,String>>` from your existing CSV parser, apply some heuristics<sup>1</sup> to convert to the corresponding `JsonNode` structure (whatever that might be).

> Is it possible to parse the CSV rows into JsonNodes having the correct value types ... using an existing parser?

The answer is almost certainly No.  A well-designed<sup>2</sup> general purpose CSV parser won't emit JSON data structures, and a well-designed<sup>2</sup> general purpose JSON parser won't accept CSV format input.

---

But reading between the lines, I suspect that you are using `JsonNode` just because it is a convenient way of representing loosely typed information.  But Strings work just as well (as pure representation), and you can implement the conversion to (more) typed representations using a simple custom utility or wrapper class.

---

<sup>1 - Herein lies a problem.  CSV is essentially typeless, so you need to use a heuristic to tell you if a value, is a boolean, an integer, a floating point number, or a string.  But the conversion is ambiguous, and the lines in a CSV file can be inconsistent. So your conversion to `JsonNode` objects is liable to be unreliable if you don't have a "schema" for the CSV file.</sup>

<sup>2 - In both cases, this would violate the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC) design principle.  This does not mean that such an API would *always* be wrong.  Sometimes it is appropriate to ignore design principles in specific circumstances for pragmatic reasons.  However, such a design would not be general purpose.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for reading between the lines and for your explanations.